# Reading in quoted environment variable new line

Tags: python

I need to read in an env variable which must be quoted when exported

```
export ENV_QUOTES="cat\nhat" # This is actually a rsa private key
export ENV_NO_QUOTES=cat\nhat
```

When I read in the quoted env var it does not register the escaped newline:

```
import os
env_var_no_quotes = os.environ['ENV_NO_QUOTES']
env_var = os.environ['ENV_QUOTES']
for idx, v in enumerate(env_var_no_quotes):
    print(idx, v, env_var[idx])
```

Output:

```
0 c c
1 a a
2 t t
3 n \
4 h n
5 a h
6 t a
```

How do I get python to recognize newlines for env vars that are quoted? The actual output `print` the private keys looks like this:

```
# Non quoted
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
ffaffdsafsdeeekqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCltThZlt88aAn8
f2MlQsV4Nv9TEhBj8WUypfGc148FedpTRraNyE3f9bZ4u4MJC34vI9zuqf5hNrX+
+w+eYrPJwbS4CvA3Ww2znjCfKK4u3n3P522LTGNxAoGBAK5AA0twCSifwIPIlIsZ
psGtFIEJpc6sJ4+LgVzTW/5EwreMHMnx3tQTaVi6pVIJTqjaMJp5SAAUlPrl5zZM
gsVgtwyXMMqlKNt9wMdBH+ir7oJsppC+DjIRbpCa8U6nEG4Wij5qVeRJ8DVV8NAM
C5Tc+6qgzVZRaXXkCStZA/PK
    -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

    # Quoted
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nMIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQCltThZlt88aAn8\nf2MlQsV4Nv9TEhBj8WUypfGc148FedpTRraNyE3f9bZ4u4MJC34vI9zuqf5hNrX+\nW+UfXJkPLfemupraI5sTWyFCwX7ZYOd5I7vyRoqSii4MHCXlg8zWySrjwirwou87\nn18zSyA30fu3kuHBDlHFnRVw+Ag+M/XjesRcz5Q+KQ9o/MnpcZcYQ7sZU5GntqCw\n3ZNgb68Cla87jbhvlkjfdN77IcLJypuwCMZeyHeQYNtgxLyE0o2Te5ddAjvD59uS\nML69iuQqpvPjpuBgZnReKX3oZusU/o6qgzVZRaXXkCStZA/PK\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n
```

Comment: Have you checked the values in these variables some other way, for example, the `printenv` utility?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your Python -- you aren't assigning the variable correctly in shell. Run `s=\n; echo "$s"`, and you'll see it's a single-character string containing only `n`.

Comment: Furthermore, `"\n"` is not a newline in shell, it's a two-character string that starts with a backslash. If you want to assign a newline in shell, you need to use a different quoting form, ie. `$'\n'`

Answer (score 9):

If you can't change the shell script assigning your input to correctly contain a newline literal (which is the better approach!), you can simply use `string.sub()` in Python to replace `r'\n'` (which is what the variable actually contains) with `'\n'` (which is what you want):

```
env_var = os.environ['ENV_QUOTES'].replace(r'\n', '\n')
```

---

That said, on the shell side, consider:

```
# in bash or ksh, not POSIX sh
ENV_QUOTES=$'cat\nhat'    # literal newline, not '\' followed by 'n'
```

...or...

```
# in any POSIX shell
orig_shell_var='cat\nhat'                 # two characters, '\' then 'n'
ENV_QUOTES=$(printf %b "$orig_shell_var") # evaluated as format string, now has newline
export ENV_QUOTES
```

...or...

```
# in any POSIX shell
ENV_QUOTES='cat
hat'
```